# Conversion between semicircles and latitude units

Tags: latitude-longitude, units

I've recently come across the semicircle unit that is used to describe a latitude and longitude using the maximum precision allowed by a 32-bit number. The conversion [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc510650.aspx) is given as

- `degrees = semicircles * ( 180 / 2^31 )`
- `semicircles = degrees * ( 2^31 / 180 )`

However it doesn't explain if this should be used differently for latitude since the maximum allowed number of semicircles is 2^31, and if you substitute this into the equation you get the answer "180 degrees", but latitude only goes up to 90.

Would a different conversion between latitude be used instead? Such as:

- `degrees = semicircles * ( 90 / 2^31 )`
- `semicircles = degrees * ( 2^31 / 90 )`

If so then you wouldn't be using the 'semicircle' as a unit for latitude, more like a quarter circle in this case.

Has anybody else come across this issue?

Answer (score 4):

The constant 180 would still be used for latitude because the relationship is 1 degree to a half circle. The Max and Min semicircles for latitude will be different (.5 to -.5) vs. Max and Min semicircles for longitude (1.0 to -1.0).

Answer (score 1):

I have problems with [@longrider saying](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/168174/107424) that

> the relationship is 1 degree to a half circle.

which does not make sense mathematically. And I do not think is accurate. (please elaborate if I am wrong)

This answer is copied-pasted from http://www.logicio.com/HTML/navstopset.htm in case the link breaks.

> A semicircle is a unit of location-based measurement on an arc. An arc
> of 180 degrees is made up of many semicircle units; 2^31 semicircles
> to be exact. Semicircles that correspond to North latitudes and East
> longitudes are indicated with positive values; semicircles that
> correspond to South latitudes and West longitudes are indicated with
> negative values.
>
> The following formulas show how to convert between degrees and
> semicircles:
>
> degrees = semicircles * (180 / 2^31)
>
> semicircles = degrees * (2^31 / 180)

This explain better the relationship between degrees and semicircles units. What I take that [@longrider](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/168174/107424) wanted to say is that the range of values of a latitude measured in semicircles (or half-circles) is -0.5 to 0.5, while the longitude ones are -1.0 to 1.0. So multiplying by 180 was ok in both cases.